# unfold function in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

**Goal:** implement `unfold` function using only two arguments.

**The arguments:**

- the first argument is f which takes an initial value of some type I and returns nil or a cons pair of two elements (the first of these two is the next element that goes in the list of some type A and the next initial value again of some type I).
- The second argument is an initial value of some type I and the return is a list of items of type A.

This is what I have so far and I am not sure why it is not working:

```
(define (descending i)
  (if (= i 0)
    (list)
    (cons i (- i 1))))

(define nil (list))

(define (unfold f init)
  (if (eq? (f init) '())
    (list)
    (cons init (unfold f (f init)))))

(unfold (descending 5))
```

should evaluate to

```
'(5 4 3 2 1)
```

This should be the result but isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it should be `(unfold descending 5)`. Then `f` would produce a pair and you would use both components of it,

```lisp
(define (unfold f init)
  (if (eq? (f init) '())
      (list)
      (cons (car (f init)) (unfold f (cdr (f init))))))
```

But this has awful computational complexity as it calls `(f init)` three times per iteration. A humble [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) binding remedies this.

```
(define (unfold f init)
  (let ((r (f init)))
    (if (empty? r) ;; instead of (eq? r '())
        (list)
        (cons (car r) (unfold f (cdr r))))))
```

And a tail recursive form using [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29)

```
(define (unfold f init)
  (let loop ((acc empty)
             (state (f init)))
    (if (empty? state)
        (reverse acc)
        (loop (cons (car state) acc)
              (f (cdr state))))))
```

And using [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html).

```
(define (unfold f init)
  (let loop ((acc empty)
             (state (f init)))
    (match state
      ((cons x next)
       (loop (cons x acc)
             (f next)))
      (empty
       (reverse acc)))))
```

Comment: I see! Thanks! Also if I want to define an ascending function that returns '(-100...100) I am not sure why the following code stops at -5: (define (ascending i)
  (if (= i (- i))
      (list)
      (cons i (+ i 5))))
(unfold ascending (- 100))

Comment: Your condition there is `(= i (- i))`, which is equivalent to `(= i 0)`, so it stops at 0 and the last to be consed is `-5`.

Comment: I guess I just have to do (= i (105)) then. I just thought I could define the function such that it would print all number up to an including the negative of the initial.

Comment: Is `(eq? whatever '())` really canonical Scheme or is this some inside joke referencing http://ashwinram.org/1986/01/28/a-short-ballad-dedicated-to-the-growth-of-programs/

Comment: @Kaz No idea whether that's canonical or a code smell. What I know about Lisp, Scheme etc. fits inside a matchbox. The question originally also had a [tag:haskell] tag, that's how I came across it. I understood enough to answer it, so I did, using the OP's code as much as possible.