# working with lists in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I have this function:

```
(define (unfold f init)
  (if (eq? (f init) '())
    (list)
    (cons (car (f init)) (unfold f (cdr (f init))))))
```

I want to use it to define a function that does:

```
(hypothetical-function '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

which should return:

```
'((1 2 3 4 5) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5) (4 5) (5)
```

Comment: And, what is the problem with it?

Comment: Also, what is the relation between `function` and `unfold`?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my unfold! I want to use unfold in defining function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unfold function in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286014/unfold-function-in-scheme)

Comment: Again, I am not trying to implement the unfold function because I have already done that! I am trying to define a function that takes a list and returns a list of lists such that each list has the first element removed like above.

Comment: check out [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/a9WcS), it's got scheme (not racket though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you want

```
(define (tails xs) (unfold foo xs))
```

and for that you need to define the appropriate `foo`. Now, what should `foo` do? It should return a pair, the first component of which becomes the `car` of the resulting list, and the second component of which becomes the seed for the recursive call - unless the unfolding is to stop, when `foo` should return an empty list. So

```
(define (foo xs)
    (if (stop-condition)
        '()
        (cons car-of-result next-seed)))
```

Filling in the remaining details is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: (define (all-suffixes list) (unfold delete list))
(define (delete list)
    (if (null? list)
        (list)
        (cons (car list) (cdr list))))

Comment: Right. `cons (car list) (cdr list)` is usually just `list`, so that's not what you want.

Comment: ah so then (cons (car list) (delete (cdr list))

Comment: No. In your example, what's the first element of the desired result?

Comment: the first element of the desired result is the original lis

Comment: I am sorry I have to use the computer at a cafe and it doesn't have racket or anything on it so I can't run my functions. I am trying to finish reading a textbook and doing the exercises in my head.

Comment: I am supposed to be defining a function that USES unfold to return a list of all the suffixes of the original list.

Comment: Don't do that¹. Use pencil and paper. Or wait till you get home/to uni/wherever where a racket/scheme/guile is available. ¹(doing the exercises in your head)